# BitCoin Payment Using StripeConnect

Tags: stripe-payments, bitcoin, stripe-connect

I am using StripeConnect to charge customer on behalf of our connect Merchants. When I am charging using Credit/Debit Cards its working fine. I used merchant_stripe_access_token to create BitCoin Receiver and using same merchant_stripe_access_token to charge after getting confirmation that BitCoin are filled. Please let me know what did I missed.

```
stripe_bitcoin_receiver = Stripe::BitcoinReceiver.create(
{
    amount:             dollar_to_cents(amount),
    currency:           currency,
    description:        charge_description,
    refund_mispayments: true,
    email:              user.email,
    metadata:           charge_metadata
},
merchant_stripe_access_token
)
```

> {"id":"btcrcv_17MHRCDtBWPHkYdT2Cte9Oay","object":"bitcoin_receiver","active":false,"amount":2845,"amount_received":0,"bitcoin_amount":28450000,"bitcoin_amount_received":0,"bitcoin_uri":"bitcoin:test_3Bb3YdEqU6Xmqb141YleVZ2BqhYk9?amount=0.28450000","created":1451133982,"currency":"usd","customer":null,"description":"Charge for Invoice #166B","email":"najeebidrees@gmail.com","filled":false,"inbound_address":"test_3Bb3YdEqU6Xmqb141YleVZ2BqhYk9","livemode":false,"metadata":{"First Name":"Najeeb","Last Name":"Idrees","Email":"najeebidrees@gmail.com"},"payment":null,"refund_address":null,"transactions":{"object":"list","data":[],"has_more":false,"total_count":0,"url":"/v1/bitcoin/receivers/btcrcv_17MHRCDtBWPHkYdT2Cte9Oay/transactions"},"uncaptured_funds":false,"used_for_payment":false}"

## After its filled successufully.

```
stripe_charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
{
    amount:               dollar_to_cents(amount),
    currency:             currency,
    source:               stripe_bitcoin_receiver.id,
    description:          charge_description,
    application_fee:      dollar_to_cents(application_fee),
    capture:              is_captured,
    statement_descriptor: statement_descriptor,
    metadata:             charge_metadata
},
merchant_stripe_access_token
)
```

Getting this error.

## Stripe::InvalidRequestError: (Status 404) No such bitcoin receiver: btcrcv_17MHRCDtBWPHkYdT2Cte9Oay

Comment: are you sure merchant_stripe_access_token is  set in both api calls and that it doesn't accidentally get set to null / empty string?

Comment: yes I have verified it and its Okey